# Samba3 and Windows 8 RTM

Tags: windows-8, samba

So I have just got a new PC that has come pre-installed with Windows 8 (shudder...).  The guy its for likes to live on the edge and wants to keep it, rather than just go back to Win7.

The network it is on runs Samba3 with a current mix of XP & Win7 clients.  All Win7 clients have the compatibility mode registry keys set to join the Samba3 domain.

```
HKLM\System\CCS\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
DWORD  DomainCompatibilityMode = 1
DWORD  DNSNameResolutionRequired = 0
```

With Windows8 however, it doesnt seem to matter what I try it always wants to try and join an AD style domain.  With the registry keys, a reboot, and a join attempt I get:

```
The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "<BLAH>":

The error was: "DNS name does not exist."
(error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.<BLAH>
```

Some people seem to report success with Windows8 on Samba3.  Does anyone know if this is still present in the RTM version of if its Beta/MSDN only?

Samba4 is not an option ;o)

Thanks

Comment: Why "Shudder" with Windows 8? In my experience thus far with windows 8 (my main OS since DevPreview), I have found it to be a very robust system.

As for Samba3 Domains.... I'll need to do some research...

Comment: Its crashed 3 times since I have had it, before installing anything at all.  Dev studio 2010 keeps barfing as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to my Windows 8 install right now, so I haven't tried this yet, but...

go to

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation
```

locate the key

```
DependOnService
```

remove

```
MRxSmb20
```

and reboot

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still does the same.  My DependsOn is now bowser,mrxsmb10,nsi. Reboot.  Same thing.

Comment: Bah! Well I won't be trying that then. I've been following various threads on this since September last year! Nobody seems to have an actual answer as to whether MS are going to accomodate S3 or just go with S4.

Comment: Yes... Well we had the option of Win7 on the PC but he wanted Win8.  I said OK based on a bit of searching and people saying yes it works.  I can only think they have pulled it from the RTM version... A bit more digging shows `LManworkstation` is reading the `DomainCompatibilityMode` registry key, but not the `DNSNameResolutionRequired` key.